# Deployment projects for multiple sites

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have 7 sites that should be deployed to my DEV server, then to my QA server and in the end to the PROD servers.

Currently everything is done manually, but it's a chore. Today I looked at the Deployment solutions, but it seems it's one deployment solution per site.
Is there a way to have multiple sites deployed with one action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this yet?:

[Web Deployment tool](http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like Wise or Install Shield?

Install shield is actually my flavour of choice and Yes you can role out anything, with any settings you could think of.